# Batch file for dumping specific words

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file that does want I want it to do perfectly, it searches through all files in its directory, and dumps the string with the word I searched. However, I want to be able to enter 2 words to search. Is anyone able to help?

```
@echo off
title Dumper
color 2
:start
cls
set input=
set /p input= Name To Dump :
findstr /s /i "%input%" *.*  > "%input%_dump.txt"
if %errorlevel%==0 (
echo Dumped All Occurrences For %input% Into %input%_dump.txt
) else (
echo No Data Found
timeout /t 5000
goto start
)
timeout /t 5000
cls
goto start
```

Comment: What do you mean by "2 words to search[for]" Do you mean you want **both** or **either**?

Comment: I want to enter the first word, then the second. And have it search for both at the same time (if it's possible)

Comment: When your `SET /P` executes enter in both of your search terms separated by a space.  Findstr by default will treat them both as separate search terms.

Comment: Thanks, that was my stupidity. May I ask how to make the output not list the filename before the string? Sorry but I am clueless about this stuff

Comment: Put the `findstr` command inside a `FOR /F` in clause.  This will parse the output of the `findstr` command and you can use the `delims` option of the `FOR /F` command to get rid of the file name by using the colon as the delimiter.

Comment: To search for *either* words, use `findstr /L "word1 word2" *.*`; to search for *both* words, use `findstr /L "word1" *.* | findstr /L "word2"`...

Comment: @aschipfl, you can do both words with one `findstr` command. `findstr /i /r /c:"hello.*goodbye" /c:"goodbye.*hello"`

Comment: Yes, @Squashman, good idea! there are several possibilities (even using `find`); but I wanted to avoid regular expressions (`/R`), because I do not know what "words" to be search for, hence some escaping of meta characters might become necessary then...

Comment: Thanks guys! I forgot to mention I want to search this character as well "{" but it gives a weird result